# How to do a conversion using Fuse file system?

Tags: c, fuse

I'm getting this error:

> Error: invalid conversion from `int (*)(const char*, fuse_file_info*)` to `int (*)(const char*, int)`

when i do

```
static struct fuse_operations vkfs_opers;

...

vkfs_opers.open = vkfs_open;
```

but function is declarated as

```
static int vkfs_open (const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
```

and in structure `fuse_operations` it declarated as

```
int (*open) (const char *, struct fuse_file_info *);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try #define FUSE_USE_VERSION 26 before including `<fuse.h>`.

Source of solution is [this discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.fuse.devel/4450).

Answer (score 0):

What you've done seems correct, so I don't know why you are getting that error. My first guess would be that its a side effect of some other error. Is that the only error you get when you compile, or are there others?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a makefile add to your CFLAGS the appropriate define -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 
so you want a line like this:  CFLAGS += -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26